# Define Fill Value for NoData areas during/after reprojection

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm using rasterio to reproject rasters. The following code snippet should show roughly what I'm trying:

```
profile = {'crs': proj4_str,
                   'nodata': np.nan,
                   'dtype': str(dem.height.encoding['dtype']),
                   'count': 1,
                   'transform': dst_transform,
                   'interleave': 'band',
                   'driver': 'GTiff',
                   'width': nx,
                   'height': ny,
                   'tiled': False}

        with rasterio.open(dem_out, 'w', **profile) as dest:
            dst_array = np.empty((ny, nx),
                                 dtype=str(dem.height.encoding['dtype']))
            dst_array[:] = np.nan

            reproject(
                # Source parameters
                source=dem_arr,
                src_crs=dem.pyproj_srs,
                src_transform=src_transform,
                # Destination parameters
                destination=dst_array,
                dst_transform=dst_transform,
                dst_crs=proj4_str,
                # Configuration
                resampling=resampling)

            dest.write(dst_array, 1)
```

Not caring about the values of single parameters, I run into the problem after reprojection there are areas on my grid which are covered with zeroes. However, I would like to have them covered also with NaNs. That's why I'm saying in the profile that `nodata` should be np.nan, and fill the dst_array also with NaNs. But it doesn't help:

[image]

If I sample the dark blue area, it has the values zero. Does anybody know how I can change this?

Comment: I believe you're confusing the purpose of the 'nodata' parameter. It is used to tell the driver which values in the raster it's writing should be considered nodata. You are thinking that it is the value that the driver assigns to nodata pixels, but the driver doesn't know which pixels are nodata until you tell it. You could try setting nodata to 0 and see what happens.

Comment: Good comment, my intention was to say "this is the only NaN setting I could find". I tried your option though and unfortunately found the same result, as the zeroes I am talking about are even outside raster area itself.

Comment: Why is there so much "extra" space at the bottom of your raster? What are those values in the pre-projected raster? Whatever they are is what you should set your NoData value as.

Comment: The extra space is due to the fact that I try to reproject the tile of an elevation model to a local grid with a fixed extent (nx, ny). The tile covers only part of this local grid. I thought I would set the values outside the tile to np.nan by `dst_array[:] = np.nan`. But, correct me, you're saying that I have to expand the tile with NaN to a bigger area and then reproject?

Comment: I've never tried to reproject a raster into a pre-created array, but what you have looks like it should work. I found this: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/342, which makes me wonder if you should pass in a nodata=np.nan parameter to your "reproject" command.

Comment: That was it, perfect!!!!! :-) Passing a `dst_nodata=np.nan` did the job. Thanks a lot for your effort, I was not able to find this documented somewhere. I think you deserve posting this as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/342) with rasterio, and you should be able to overcome it by applying a nodata parameter when you reproject. Based on your current code, setting

```
dst_nodata=np.nan
```

in your reproject command should replace the zeros with nodata.

Comment: Wait, I tried your solution anf found that you have to pass explicitly `dst_nodata=np.nan`, otherwise it's still zero. Maybe you can edit your answer according to this.